# Specflow: Read example table data in BeforeScenario or AfterScenario hook

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, bdd, specflow, gherkin

Consider the below scenario,

```
@regression @msexcel
Scenario Outline: Open all supported excel formats from windows explorer
Given I navigate to a windows explorer directory named <directoryName>
Examples:
 | directoryName         | excelDocumentName               | expectedTitle                                        |
 | OfficeDocuments\Excel | Excel2016_3Worksheets_XLSM.xlsm | Excel2016_3Worksheets_XLSM.pdf [Read-Only] - pdfDocs |
 | OfficeDocuments\Excel | Excel2016_3Worksheets_XLT.xlt   | Excel2016_3Worksheets_XLT.pdf [Read-Only] - pdfDocs  |
```

I would like to read the example table in before or after scenario hook. Is that possible? If so, Please help with the suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I don't think you can do what you want (as the outline is turned into several independent scenarios when the tests are generated) but if we can understand your root problem we may be able to off additional solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SpecFlow hooks such as [BeforeScenario] and [AfterScenario] to execute your code.

Source:
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, my question not how to use specflow hooks as I'm aware of it. I want to know how to access specflow table data within a hook

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the ScenarioContext via Dependency Injection (http://www.specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/)
2. `scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Table`

Comment: This doesn't work because the scenario context is null during BeforeFeature.